# Open a file to view the content through adb. (Android, Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, file

I have recently created some code which writes just some text to a file called 'config.txt', however; I want to be able to open this textfile and view its contents.

I have navigated to the file through the eclipse file explorer, but found you can't actually open the file from there.

Which commands do I need in order to open this file and view its contents?

I know this question has been asked before, but I have not yet found any commands which do not lead to an error message; or simply nothing happening.

Thanks for any help.

Callum

UPDATE

I think I have just answered my own question.

I did not realise that in the top left of the file explorer window, there is an icon which allows you to pull selected files from the device to your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to download that file form your AVD to your computer via the "pull a file from the device" symbol in the top right corner first.

By the way, I asked a question about working with files in the AVD a few days ago. Unfortunately, I got no answer but there are some links in that question that might help you choose the way you prefer. So if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013091/avd-android-virtual-device-sd-card-file-management

Comment: ok, you have answered your own question already. I was too slow once again. As always here on SO. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out haha. Spent 1 hour looking for this solution xD Thanks for the links, I will be sure to look at them! +1

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could use adb from a command line if you are familiar with that (or willing to learn). :)

`adb pull <remote> <local>` would get the file similar to what you did with the GUI.

Or open an adb shell and read it from that session: `cat <filename>`.